# Build apache 1.3 modules (in particular mod_rewrite and mod_alias)

Tags: apache, compilation, apache-modules

for study purposes I have to install an 1.3 version of the apache web server.
Problem is that I don't know how to build modules, moreover in the installation directory I can't see any "modules" folder.

I'd like to recompile and reinstall the server with some modules I need, like mod_rewrite (with LDAP support) and mod_alias...can you tell me how to do that?

Unfortunately documentation is mainly for 2.x versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run ./configure you can enable modules with --enable-module and enable-sahre for example:

```
./configure --enable-module=rewrite --enable-shared=rewrite
```

for a complete list of modules that come with apache check the configure help

```
./configure --help
```

Additionally if you are trying to compile apache on a modern linux system this blog post gives a few pointers that are helpful.
http://www.cambus.net/compiling-apache-1.3.x-on-modern-linux-distributions/